# how to concatenate two Rich Text fields

Tags: formula-field, richtextarea

I want to concatenate multiple Rich text values. But formula functions doesn't allow that? whats the solution

Comment: You need to populate a formula field be rich text fields is it?

Comment: Vote up this idea -- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhEAAS while you do what guy suggests

Answer (score 1):

Rich text area fields aren't available for formulas.  If you need this information you'll need to use a workflow field update or an APEX trigger to copy it.

Unfortunately when using a Workflow Field Update the markup (html) is lost.

So depending on what is in the rich text fields:

- if they are text-only, you can use a workflow rule to concatenate and write to the new field
- if you need markup as well then you'll have to revert to Apex Triggers